# What does the Warlock's Fey Presence ability actually do?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock

The PHB says about the Warlock's **Fey Presence**:

> As an action, you can cause each creature in a 10-foot cube originating from you to make a Wisdom saving throw against your warlock spell save DC. The creatures that fail their saving throws are all charmed or frightened by you (your choice) until the end of your next turn.

But what does the text actually mean by "charmed" or "frightened"? Are these just the normal emotions? Are they magical effects?

Answer (score 9):

Charmed and Frightened are terms referring to conditions, described in the appendix of the basic rules or PHB:

> [Charmed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Charmed):
>
> - A charmed creature can't attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects
> - The charmer has advantage on any ability checks to interact socially with the creature
>
> [Frightened](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Frightened):
>
> - A frightened creature has disadvantage on ability checks and attack rolls while the source of its fear is within line of sight
> - The creature can't willingly move closer to the source of its fear

Comment: Answers are required to stand on their own as an answer to the question. Please add sufficient information to make this a complete answer.

Comment: @miniman in what way does this NOT stand on its own? It quotes RAW and directly answers the question in far more detail than the original +1 from me

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, it just gives the rules for 2 conditions without explanation.

Comment: The rules for those two conditions WAS the question. If you think my answer wasn't complete enough, feel free to give your own.

Comment: I think the answer just needed a brief introductory statement, which I've edited in. Hopefully that's acceptable.

Answer (score 8):

*Charmed* and *Frightened* are **Conditions** (or in unofficial game terms can be thought of as "debuffs").

Rules for **Conditions** can be found on page 290 of the *PHB.*